# Why is the formula for the speed of sound in solids different from that in liquids and gases?

Tags: waves, acoustics

We know that sound waves are longitudinal waves and that the propagation of longitudinal waves depends on the bulk modulus $B$ (volumetric elasticity). Why, then, does the speed of sound in a solid depend on the Young’s modulus $Y$ of the medium and the density,
$$v = \sqrt{(Y/\text{density of the medium})}?$$
The form should be the same as for liquids and gases:
$$v = \sqrt{(B/\text{density of the medium})}.$$

Answer (score 9):

There is more than one speed of sound in a solid. In an isotropic solid the  speed depend on the two [Lame coeffcients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lam%C3%A9_parameters) $\lambda$ and $\mu$.   The  speed of longitudinal "p" waves in a bulk solid is
$$
c_{p}= \sqrt{\frac{E(1-\nu)}{\rho(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}}
$$
where
$$
E=\mu\left(\frac{3\lambda+2\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)
$$
is Young's modulus and
$$
\nu=\frac 12 \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}
$$
is Poisson's ratio.
The speed of transverse "s" waves is
$$
c_s= \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\rho}}.
$$
The simple formula
$$
c_{rod}= \sqrt{\frac {E}{\rho}}
$$
applies only to longitudinal waves in a long thin rod.

The physical reason for the differences in the longitudinal speeds is  that in a long thin rod, the material is free to contract laterally as the wave propagates, but in the infinite medium it is not.

Comment: Is the short answer that the Poisson's ratio of a fluid $\nu = 0$ which makes the first expression $c_p = c_{rod}$.

Comment: No. It is the  *shear modulus* $\mu$ of a fluid that is zero. The fluid cannot sustain shear waves. Then  Poisson's ratio is $\nu=1/2$ and Young's modulus is zero. This is because you can stretch a fluid with no effort as long as you allow it to shrink transversely so that its volume stays fixed. In a fluid it is the bulk modulus $\kappa$ that counts, and with  $\mu=0$ we have $\kappa=\lambda$ and $c_{fluid}= \sqrt{\kappa/\rho}$.

Comment: Nice. The above comment completes the answer as it bridges liquids to solids.