# Speed of sound in thin rods vs infinite solids

Tags: waves, acoustics

This is a followup to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/609188/341916), which states that there are two different sound velocities in a solid depending on the geometry:

1. For 3-dimensional, infinite solids, in which the boundaries are much bigger than the wavelength, we have
   $$v = \sqrt{\frac{E(1-\nu)}{\rho(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}}$$
2. In contrast, for thin rods, in which the wavelength is larger than the diameter, we have
   $$v = \sqrt{\frac {E}{\rho}}$$

But these are only for two extreme cases (wavelength significantly smaller than diameter and wavelength significantly bigger than diameter).

What about for non-thin rods with dimensions that are similar to the wavelength? For instance, if we start with a thin rod and keep increasing its diameter, then surely the speed of sound must continuously transition between the second equation and the first equation, but I can find no mention of this nor any theory that would describe these in-between speeds of sound. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Limiting cases such as $d\ll \lambda$ and $d \gg \lambda$, where $d$ is the transverse extent/boundary of the object and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the acoustic wave, allow us to deduce analytical, closed-form results such as the ones you mentioned. Certainly, as you said, as we vary $d$ from much less than $\lambda$ to much greater than $\lambda$, the speed will generally interpolate between those two analytical formulae. But the intermediate result may not expressible in closed-form.

Comment: A similar situation arises in beam bending vs. plate bending. Beams are narrow and can laterally expand and contract freely (from Poisson effects) on the bottom and top, respectively (for downward bending). Plates can't laterally deform in this way—there's too much plate in the way. So plates end up being stiffer by a factor of $\frac{1}{1-\nu^2}$, corresponding to the so-called plane-strain modulus. Wide beams or narrow plates can thus necessitate a numerical solution.

Comment: Are there any numerical treatments of the problem that allow for determining the speed of sound theoretically?